# RewriteRule not working, 404 error obtained

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

Using Apache/2.2.31, I created the following rule on my '.htaccess' file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ /do.php?label=$1 [L]
```

However, when accessing 'http://foo.com/whatever/', I get a 404 error message. I've checked my error log and:

```
[Mon Jun 27 11:12:15 2016] [error] [client 192.168.1.132] File does not exist: /path-to-web/whatever, referer: http://foo.com/
```

'http://foo.com' works ok, and 'http://foo.com/do.php?label=whatever' works ok as well.

I've checked phpinfo, and 'mod_rewrite' is loaded in Apache. Additionally, I tried to enable it via 'http.conf', but Apache tells me that "module rewrite_module is built-in and can't be loaded".

What am I doing wrong? This same '.htaccess' works ok in two other Apache servers.

I tried with "Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews" as well

Thank you very much

Comment: The RewriteRule that you are using expects the incoming request to end with a "/". So, `http://foo.com/whatever` returns a 404. Accessing `http://foo.com/whatever/` (note the last forward slash) will send the request to `http://foo.com/do.php?label=whatever`.

Comment: Thank you, nidhi. However, I had tried with http://foo.com/whatever/ (in fact, it was a typo on my question, which I've just edited).

Comment: I fixed it. I modified "httpd.conf", replacing "AllowOverride None" with "AllowOverride All" within the "<Directory>".